# Display VM guest on same monitor as Hyper-V Core

Tags: hyper-v

So I'll be running 2 VM's on a new bare metal Hyper-V Core install:

i) A Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller and
ii) A Windows Server 2019 application server

When I've done this before, the screen attached to the server only displays the text user interface for Hyper-V Core. Not a problem for that scenario as all management is done through Hyper-V Manager on a domain joined workstation or by remoting in.

However for this scenario, the owner will need to use an application on the Application Server itself.

So the question is: Is it possible to display the desktop of either VM on the same physical monitor that normally displays the Hyper-V Core text only UI?

I'm wondering whether to just go with a Windows Server 2019 install onto the bare metal instead and use as the Application Server as there's actually only one Application that needs to be run on it and none of the existing workstations are domain joined anyway (don't ask - it's a set-up I've inherited) so there will be no domain controller on the new server just like there isn't one on the old server that's being replaced.

Comment: Just to add, it may not be possible to do what I'm asking with the text only UI of Hyper-V Core. So now I'm thinking 2 options:
1. App server only on bare metal - no domain controller or
2. Domain Controller on bare metal running Hyper-V and App Server as a VM guest on it.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you mean the free Hyper-V Server 2019 vs Windows Server 2019 core with Hyper-V role, then no, there's no way to view a VM on the local monitor.